# Docker run commands works but dockerfile not

Tags: docker, tomcat, dockerfile

I have a problem with running the image of Dockerfile. CLI commands work fine but when I use the Dockerfile I get an error from the localhost:

> localhost didn’t send any data.

What I am doing is simple. By CLI:

```
docker run -d --name mytomcat -p 8080:8080 tomcat:latest

docker exec -it mytomcat /bin/bash

mv webapps webapps2

mv webapps.dist/ webapps

exit
```

Which works fine.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:latest
CMD mv webapps webapps2 && mv webapps.dist/ webapps && /bin/bash
```

Build and run:

```
docker build -t myrepo/tomacat:1.00  .  
docker run -d --name mytomcat -p 8080:8080 myrepo/tomacat:1.00
```

Doesn't work and show the above error.

**Note:** I am using mv command because I get 404 error!

Does anybody know the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Dockerfile has a `CMD` command, that runs instead of the command in the base image.  With the `tomcat` image, the base image would run the Tomcat server; but with this Dockerfile, it's trying to run a `bash` shell instead, and without any input that just exits immediately.

To just moves files around, it's usually better to use `COPY` and `RUN` directives to set up the image once, rather than trying to repeat these steps every time you run the container.  For this setup where the base image already has a reasonable `CMD`, you don't need to repeat it in your own custom Dockerfile.

```bash
FROM tomcat:latest
RUN mv webapps webapps2 && mv webapps.dist/ webapps
# no particular mention of bash; use the `CMD` from the base image
```

It's not uncommon for a base image to include some sort of runtime that needs to be configured, but for the base image's `CMD` to still be correct.  In addition to `tomcat`, `nginx` and `php:fpm` work similarly; so long as their configuration files and code are in the right place, you don't need to repeat the `CMD`.

Comment: I learned a new point here. Thanks, @David